# Conversion to Automatic Reference Counting (ARC): 'Use of undeclared identifier' errors

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, properties, compilation, automatic-ref-counting

In one of the very big projects I used auto-synthesized properties everywhere:

```
//MyClass.h file:
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *deviceName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *deviceID;

@end

//MyClass.m file:
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation ApplicationStatus
// no @synthesize used at all.

-(void)dealloc{

    [_deviceName release]; // gives errors only while converting to ARC with LLVM 5.0
    [_deviceID release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The code above compiles well in non-ARC mode and also in older Xcode versions during ARC conversion process.
When trying to convert in using newest LLVM 5.0 compiler (newest Xcode) it gives me millions of errors:
[image]

What is the cause of this? Do I have to manually create hundreds of instance variables and @synthesize them manually now? Wouldn't that be step back from 'write less code' philosophy Apple advertised on all WWDCs?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this issue at all? I'm experiencing the same thing. so far I see two choices -- treat the error as a bug in the migration tool and just fix them all, run the migration, then undo the fixes. Alternatively you can use Xcode4 to run the migration?

Comment: I had to manually @synthesize all properties. I assume this is not a bug. It may be that ARC is just more strict about property - instance variable relationship.

Comment: I think this is a bug. I had to change all my _var references to self.var - but this fell over with all my overridden getters and setters. Had some luck moving @property declarations into public space. Still struggling with it though.

Comment: Also, try running a build in-between each Arc conversion attempt.

Comment: The problem is with Script which does not insert AutoSynthesize. Run this on Xcode 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hit the same problem.

Following Apple's guidance, I religiously use `self.` outside `init` and `_` in `init`.
This breaks as you wrote, when migrating to ARC in Xcode 5.

I found the easiest way is to:

```
@synthesise deviceName = _deviceName;
```

Changing all the references is just dumb, a pain, and wrong, and for read only variables, not even an option.

The autocomplete is pretty smart in setting up the synthesise statements, and you only need them for the stuff you're going to access in `init`.