# ARC complaining about instance vairiables

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to convert non-ARC project to use ARC but for some reason its complaining about 
the use of all instance variables.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)id myvariable;
```

results in

```
Error : "Use of undeclared variable _myvariable"
```

there are some places in my code where I don't want to modify retain count but do an assignment to the property. so I use an instance variable.

adding `@syhtnesize myvariable =_myvariable` resolves this problem but I am trying to figure out the right way to fix this.

Possible solutions:

1) Add `synthesize`

2) replace use of instance variable with `self.myvariable` and make property assigned.

EDIT: 
Extension of problem [ARC errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780336/conversion-to-automatic-reference-counting-arc-use-of-undeclared-identifier)

Comment: Those do work. You using nonatomic strong||assign? using these worked for me.

Comment: Using the instance variable **will not** keep ARC from modifying the retain count of the object. Strong ivars retain just like strong properties do. So that really isn't a going concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've hit a *backward compatibility* feature.

Since Xcode 4.4 property declarations no longer require an `@synthesize` statement and without one the compiler auto-generates an `_propertyName` instance variable.

However with an `@synthesize propertyName`, as you would pre-Xcode 4.4, then the compiler will auto-generate an `propertyName` - *note no underscore* - instance variable.

The compiler messages warning you "Use of undeclared variable _myvariable" suggest you have switched the code to use underscores but still have some `@synthesize myvariable` statements.

Your use of `@synthesize myvariable = _myvariable` specifies the name to use for the instance variable directly, and so solves your problem, but removing the `@synthesize` completely is the usual approach.

Answer (score 3):

With all the arc stuff

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Something *myVariable;
```

is accessible by both

```
self.myVariable;
```

and

```
_myVariable;
```

No need to use @synthesize

Comment: yes but using this will modify the retain count. I don't want to change retain count at some places (thats why I am using instance variable)

Comment: The whole point of ARC is to not have to deal with that.  Having it be strong changes the retain count and having it be weak does not.

Comment: ya I agree but when I convert to ARC it complains about use of _myVariable. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780336/conversion-to-automatic-reference-counting-arc-use-of-undeclared-identifier

Comment: The basic premise is that in ARC you CANNOT control the retain count directly. If you think you need to control it, you're doing something wrong. Manually accessing the iVar still changes the retain count.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you need. If you declare property:

```
@property (strong) NSString *myvariable;
```

And you want to change name of the private ivar to something different that _myvariable you have to add

`@synthesize myvariable = _myVarNewName`

but if you want to use exactly the same name with underscore on the front just remove @synthesize (works with iOS 6 and above) and the compiler do the rest so you can access the private variable like _myvariable or public like self.myvariable.